# Array Combining and Posting

Tags: php, arrays

This is a follow-up question to my previous post about array posting. I was advised to combine my arrays in order to dynamically generate table results for an email. So far, it looks like this:

```
$emp_names = is_array($_POST['emp_name']) ? $_POST['emp_name'] : array($_POST['emp_name']);
$emp_today_results = is_array($_POST['emp_today_result']) ? $_POST['emp_today_result'] : array($_POST['emp_today_result']);
$emp_today_goals = is_array($_POST['emp_today_goal']) ? $_POST['emp_today_goal'] : array($_POST['emp_today_goal']);
$emp_month_results = is_array($_POST['emp_month_result']) ? $_POST['emp_month_result'] : array($_POST['emp_month_result']);
$emp_month_goals = is_array($_POST['emp_month_goal']) ? $_POST['emp_month_goal'] : array($_POST['emp_month_goal']);
$emp_month_trends = is_array($_POST['emp_month_trend']) ? $_POST['emp_month_trend'] : array($_POST['emp_month_trend']);

$emp_results = array_combine($emp_names, $emp_today_results, $emp_today_goals, $emp_month_results, $emp_month_goals, $emp_month_trends);
```

That collects and combines all the arrays. Then, I don't now how to use them. This doesn't work (I assume because there is no "as" in the brackets. Any idea how to make it work?

```
foreach ($emp_results) {
        $htmlBody .= "

        <tr>
        <td>{$emp_name}</td>
        <td>{$emp_today_result}</td>
        <td>{$emp_today_goal}</td>
        <td>{$emp_month_result}</td>
        <td>{$emp_month_goal}</td>
        <td>{$emp_month_trend}</td>
        </tr>";

        }
```

Comment: `array_combine` takes 2 arguments only.

Comment: Oh, I see. Any suggestion on how to return each value that belongs to $emp_name?

Comment: Tip: you can shorten your lines like this: `$emp_xxx = (array)$_POST['emp_xxx'];` - it forces an array where there isn't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$values = explode('|', 'emp_name|emp_today_result|emp_today_goal|emp_month_result|emp_month_goal|emp_month_trend');
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $$value = (array)$_POST[$value];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($emp_name); $i++) {
    $emp_results = array();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $emp_results[] = ${$value}[$i];
    }
    $htmlBody .= '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $emp_results) . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Your answer at least returns the values, but the values were all returned on a single row.

Comment: Still nothing. The values are actually showing up all in one row with the values alternating. Instead of Mike 1 2 3 in the first row and John 4 5 6 in the second row, I get Mike John 1 4 2 5 3 6 all in one row.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.. You don't need `array_combine` here

```
$emp_names = is_array($_POST['emp_name']) ? $_POST['emp_name'] : array($_POST['emp_name']);
$emp_today_results = is_array($_POST['emp_today_result']) ? $_POST['emp_today_result'] : array($_POST['emp_today_result']);
$emp_today_goals = is_array($_POST['emp_today_goal']) ? $_POST['emp_today_goal'] : array($_POST['emp_today_goal']);
$emp_month_results = is_array($_POST['emp_month_result']) ? $_POST['emp_month_result'] : array($_POST['emp_month_result']);
$emp_month_goals = is_array($_POST['emp_month_goal']) ? $_POST['emp_month_goal'] : array($_POST['emp_month_goal']);
$emp_month_trends = is_array($_POST['emp_month_trend']) ? $_POST['emp_month_trend'] : array($_POST['emp_month_trend']);

for($i=0;$i<count($emp_names);$i++)
{
$htmlBody .= "

        <tr>
        <td>$emp_name[$i]</td>
        <td>$emp_today_result[$i]</td>
        <td>$emp_today_goal[$i]</td>
        <td>$emp_month_result[$i]</td>
        <td>$emp_month_goal[$i]</td>
        <td>$emp_month_trend[$i]</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo $htmlBody;
```

Comment: I tried this but it's still not working. the $htmlBody is being sent via email by PHPMailer but the fields are still blank.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($htmlBody);` and let know the output ?

Comment: Well, there's a lot going on in this email. It's an html email generated from values posted on a different file. The var_dump gave me string(16317) " (my html email here) " with all the values still missing.

Comment: Hi, Shankar. I got this to work somewhat, but now the values are being returned as Array[0] for example. Any idea why?

Comment: Each row has a new number in the square brackets. Array[0] then new row Array[1] ... etc.